# awk + bash: combining arbitrary number of files

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have a script that takes a number of data files with identical layout but different data and combines a specified data column into a new file, like this:

```
gawk '{
        names[$1]= 1;
        data[$1,ARGIND]= $2
} END {
        for (i in names) print i"\t"data[i,1]"\t"data[i,2]"\t"data[i,3]
}' $1 $2 $3 > combined_data.txt
```

... where the row IDs can be found in the first column, and the interesting data in the second column.

This works nicely, but not for an arbitrary number of files. While I could simply add `$4 $5 ... $n` in the last line up to whatever maximum number of files I think I need, as well as add an equal `n` amount of `"\t"data[i,4]"\t"data[i,5] ... "\t"data[i,n]` in the line above that (which does seem to work even for files smaller than `n`; awk seems to disregard that `n` is larger than the number of input files in those cases), this seems like an "ugly" solution. Is there a way to make this script (or something that gives the same result) take an arbitrary number of input files?

Or, even better, can you somehow incorporate a `find` in there, that searches through subfolders and finds files matching some criterium?

Here is some sample data:

file.1

```
A      554
B       13
C      634
D       84
E        9
```

file.2:

```
C      TRUE
E      TRUE
F      FALSE
```

expected output:

```
A      554
B       13
C      634       TRUE
D       84
E        9       TRUE
F                FALSE
```

Comment: Edit your question to show concrete, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Edited with some testable sample input that works in my current implementation.

Comment: I see you added an example with 2 files but you've said your problem occurs with more than 3 files so if we provide a solution that works for the sample input you've posted how will we know if that's really going to be enough to solve your problem?

Comment: Shouldn't code that works for arbitrary number of files work equally well for two or three input files? My "problem" doesn't occur anywhere at all, I just think that my current solution for "many input files" is ugly, as it relies on hard-coding the number of input files, as I wrote in my question.

Comment: Yes but code that works for 2 input files won't necessarily work for an arbitrary number of input files. A room that can accommodate 20 beds will fit 2 beds, but a room that can accommodate 2 beds won't necessarily fit 20 beds. I didn't understand the part of your question about "n" and being larger or smaller and awk disregarding something so I skimmed it and went straight for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for (uses GNU awk for ARGIND just like your original script):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys]=$1 }
{ vals[$1,ARGIND]=$2 }
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numKeys; rowNr++) {
        key = keys[rowNr]
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=ARGIND; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[key,colNr], (colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
A       554
B       13
C       634     TRUE
D       84
E       9       TRUE
F               FALSE
```

If you don't care about the order the rows are output in then all you need is:

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{ vals[$1,ARGIND]=$2; keys[$1] }
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=ARGIND; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[key,colNr], (colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, thank you! I don't care about the ordering, so I'm using the last script. I'm not sure if I understand the second for-loop, though, still being a beginner awk-user. You iterate over the number of files (`ARGIND`), where `colNr` means "current file"? I also get the first part of the `printf` command in the loop, but not the `(colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)` part. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: colNr mean column number (for output) which just happens to be the same as file number on input. There is no "current file" in the END section. That last part is a ternary expression which means that for every column we print up to the last it will be followed by an OFS (tab) and for the last it'll be followed by an ORS (newline) instead. So the outside loop on keys goes row by row while the inside loop goes column by column in the current row.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some way to get the script to `find` (or with some other function/code) files in subfolders, without having to manually enter them all? Gets a bit tedious and is prone to human error when I have 20 files to input =P

Answer (score 0):

You can access an arbitrary number of files via redirected getline on the ARGV list (bypassing awk's default file processing (via BEGIN and exit)):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  for(i=1;i<=ARGC;++i){
    while (getline < ARGV[i]) {
      ...
      }
    }
  <END-type code>
  exit}' $(find -type f ...)
```

Comment: That will spin off into an infinite loop in some situations and will have other gotchas. Make sure to read and fully understand all the caveats related to using `getline` at http://awk.info/?tip/getline and then, usually, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this naming schema for the input files: `1` `2` ....

```
   gawk '{ 
        names[$1]=$1
        data[$1,ARGIND]=$2
      } 
      END {
        for (i in names) {
           printf("%s\t",i)
           for (x=1;x<=ARGIND;x++) {
             printf("%s\t", data[i,x])
             }
           print ""
           }
       }' [0-9]* > combined_data.txt
```

Results:

```
A   554 
B   13  
C   634 TRUE
D   84  
E   9   TRUE
F       FALSE
```

Comment: Never use `printf` with input data in the format location, e.g. use `printf "%s",$0`, not `printf $0`. Consider the difference if the input contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. The fact that your output rows were printed in the same order as the input is sheer coincidence, they are printed in "random" order due to `in`.

Comment: Very right @EdMorton ..about the *order* i supposed that **OP** does not care about because his original code. +1

Comment: You may be right, idk. It's always hard to tell from a script that doesn't behave as expected what is actually expected.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `join`,`bash`,`awk` and `tr`, if `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, etc. are sorted

**multijoin.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
function __t { 
  join -a1 -a2 -o '1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2' - "$1" | 
  awk -vFS='[ ]' '{print ($1!=""?$1:$2),$3"_"$4;}'; 
}
CMD="cat '$1'"
for i in `seq 2 $#`; do
  CMD="$CMD | __t '${@:$i:1}'";
done
eval "$CMD | tr '_' '\t' | tr ' ' '\t'";
```

or, recursive version

```
#!/bin/bash
function __t { 
  join -a1 -a2 -o '1.1 2.1 1.2 2.2' - "$1" | 
  awk -vFS='[ ]' '{print ($1!=""?$1:$2),$3"_"$4;}'; 
}
function __r { 
  if [[ "$#" -gt 1 ]]; then
    __t "$1" | __r "${@:2}"; 
  else
    __t "$1"; 
  fi
}
__r "${@:2}" < "$1" | tr '_' '\t' | tr ' ' '\t'
```

**NOTE:** the data cannot contain the character `_`, this was used as a wildcard

you get,

```
./multijoin file1 file2
```

```
A   554
B   13
C   634 TRUE
D   84
E   9   TRUE
F       FALSE
```

---

> for example, if `file3` contains

```
A    111
D    222
E    333
```

```
./multijoin file1 file2 file3
```

you get,

```
A   554       111
B   13      
C   634 TRUE    
D   84        222
E   9   TRUE  333
F       FALSE
```