# AWK prints empty line of NA's at end of file

Tags: awk

I have an older script that has been bugging me for a while now, which has a small bug in it that I haven't really gotten around to fixing, but I think it's about time. The script basically appends the columns of different files based on the ID of the rows. For example...

test1.txt:

```
a   3
b   2
```

test2.txt:

```
a   5
b   9
```

... should yield a result of:

```
a   3   5
b   2   9
```

The script itself looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gawk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } 
    { vals[$1,ARGIND]=$2; keys[$1] } 
    END {
            for (key in keys) {
                printf "%s%s", key, OFS
                for (colNr=1; colNr<=ARGIND; colNr++) {
                    printf "%s%s", vals[key,colNr], (colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
            }
            } printf "\n"
    }' $1 $2
```

... called as `$ script.sh test1.txt test2.txt`. The problem is that the result I get is not *exactly* what I should get:

```
a   3   5
b   2   9
NA  NA  NA
```

... i.e. I get a row with `NA`'s at the very end of the file. So far I've just been deleting this row manually, but it'd be nice to not have to do that. I don't really see where this weird functionality is coming from, though... Anybody got any ideas? I'm using GAWK on OSX, if that matters.

Here's some *actual* input (that's what I get for trying to make the question simple and to the point! =P)

```
target_id       length  eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000574176 596     282         6           0.825408
ENST00000575242 103     718         105         5.19804
ENST00000573052 291     291         21          2.61356
ENST00000312051 223     192         2559        46.8843
```

I'm interested in the `target_id` and `tpm` columns, the others are unimportant. My full script:

```
FILES=$(find . -name 'data.txt' | xargs)

# Get replicate names for column header
printf "%s" 'ENSTID'
for file in $FILES; do
    file2="${file/.results\/data.txt/}"
    file3="${file2/.\/*\//}"
    printf "\t%s" $file3
done
printf "\n"

gawk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } 
    { vals[$1,ARGIND]=$5; keys[$1] } 
    END {
            for (key in keys) {
                printf "%s%s", key, OFS
                for (colNr=1; colNr<=ARGIND; colNr++) {
                    printf "%s%s", vals[key,colNr], (colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
            }
            } printf "\n"
    }' $FILES
```

(i.e. all the files are named `data.txt`, but are located in differently named subfolders.)

Comment: Are the "NA"-strings in the actual output?

Comment: With `(...) | tail` I just get a blank line at the end, the `NA`s turn up if I look at the file in a text editor/Excel/Textedit.

Comment: If I remove the `printf` at the end, I get nothing there. The output stops after two lines. This may be an effect of Excel reading an empty line?

Comment: Oh, that does seem to work! Thanks ^^

Comment: Compare what you have above with the script I gave you (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33350930/1745001). See the difference? You added `printf "\n"` at the end for some reason. BTW the way you are using find is fragile - you should be using array, not a variable, to store the file names.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did seem to have added that for some reason, but I can't for the life of me remember why... Thanks, I'll check into using an array as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler idiomatic way to do it would be

```
$ cat test1.txt
a   3
b   2
$ cat test2.txt 
a   5
b   9
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{rec[$1]=$0;next}$1 in rec{print rec[$1],$2}' test1.txt test2.txt
a   3   5
b   2   9
```

**For the actual input**

```
$ cat test1.txt 
target_id       length  eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000574176 596     282         6           0.825408
ENST00000575242 103     718         105         5.19804
ENST00000573052 291     291         21          2.61356
ENST00000312051 223     192         2559        46.8843
$ cat test2.txt 
target_id       length  eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000574176 996     122         6           0.3634
ENST00000575242 213     618         105         7.277
ENST00000573052 329     291         89          2.0356
ENST00000312051 21      00          45          0.123
$ awk 'NR==FNR{rec1[$1]=$1;rec2[$1]=$5;next}$1 in rec1{printf "%-20s %-15s %-15s\n", rec1[$1],rec2[$1],$5}' test1.txt test2.txt
target_id            tpm             tpm            
ENST00000574176      0.825408        0.3634         
ENST00000575242      5.19804         7.277          
ENST00000573052      2.61356         2.0356         
ENST00000312051      46.8843         0.123
```

---

**Notes :**

1. `-v OFS="\t"` is for tab separated fields in output, order of passed files is important (Matters to first solution).
2. Hard-coding newlines as in

   ```
   printf "%-20s %-15s %-15s\n", rec1[$1],rec2[$1],$5
   ```

   is not a good idea as it renders the script less portable.You may well replace it with

   ```
   printf "%-20s %-15s %-15s", rec1[$1],rec2[$1],$5;print # same effect
   ```

**Edit : for more than two files**

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ awk 'NR==FNR{rec1[$1]=$1" "$5;next}{if($1 in rec1){rec1[$1]=rec1[$1]" "$5}else{rec1[$1]=$1" "$5}}END{for(i in rec1){if(i != "target_id"){print rec1[i];}}}' **/test*.txt
ENST00000312051 46.8843 46.8843 0.123 46.8843 0.123
ENST00000573052 2.61356 2.61356 2.0356 2.61356 2.0356
ENST00000575242 5.19804 5.19804 7.277 5.19804 7.277
ENST00000574176 0.825408 0.825408 0.3634 0.825408 0.3634
ENST77777777777 01245
ENST66666666666 7.277 7.277
$ shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Works great for the example files, but I realize that maybe they were too simple... I only need the first (IDs) and the fifth (values) columns in my real data files, and your version seems to break for those.

Comment: @Sajber : Mind posting a bit of actual input and output in the question? ;)

Comment: `I only need the first (IDs) and the fifth (values) columns in my real data files,` for both the files?

Comment: Edited the original question with example data (all files look the same, containing same IDs (first column) but different values for the fifth column. I also need to be able to input an arbitrary number of these files, as it varies depending on the experiment in question.

Comment: @Sajber : I have put the solution for the actual input files. If it suffices,  you may accept the answer.

Comment: It does work, except it only gives me the TPM values from the first and the last file (calling as above, with `(... , rec1[$1], rec2[$1],$5}' $FILES`).

Comment: @Sajber : I see the point now, you have more than two files :\ .Now, does these files follow a name pattern?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same patterns (even the same file name), just in an arbitrary number of different subfolders.

Comment: @Sajber : I have added a solution for more than one script. See if that helps

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the only reason you would get an empty line at the end of the output (which is what I get with `gawk` on OS X) is that you have a `printf "\n"` at the end of the script, which will add a newline even though you've just printed `ORS`.

Since your `bash` script is essentially an `awk` script, I would make a proper `awk` script out of it.  That would additionally save you the problem of having incorrect quoting of `$1` and `$2` in the shell script (would break on exotic filenames). This also gives you proper syntax highlighting in your favourite text editor, if it understands Awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }

{
    vals[$1,ARGIND] = $2;
    keys[$1] = 1;
}

END {
    for (key in keys) {
        printf("%s%s", key, OFS);

        for (colNr = 1; colNr <= ARGIND; colNr++) {
            printf("%s%s", vals[key,colNr], (colNr < ARGIND ? OFS : ORS));
        }
    }
}
```

The same can be done with more complex `sed` editing scripts.

Comment: Nice touch with the shebang, a fact often ignored. ++

Comment: @sjsam Yes, but I got it wrong :-) Needs to have `-f`, so can't use `env`.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to check that with the `printf "\n"`... The reason I'm using bash, however, is that the script has part of a slightly larger script that finds an arbitrary number of files with the same name in various subfolders, so I can't make it awk-only I'm afraid.

Comment: @Sajber There is nothing wrong with calling a separate `awk` script from `bash`. IMHO, that will even make the shell script cleaner.